# accessing child movieClips FlashDevelop

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have a movieClip within another MovieClip. I gave the child movieClip the instance name "hSprite" and I added it to the parent movieClip stage. Now I get an error like the following.

```
[Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property hSprite on com.objects.Hero.
```

If I remove the instance name from the child movieclip, then the error goes away. but when I add the instance name back, the error reappears again.

Keep in mind that both classes are set for export.

The parent class is embeded by a custom class which work perfectly fine. But the minute I give the child movieClip a instance name, the error starts up again.

Here is the class that embeds the parent class. What I initially want to do is access the child MovieClip that is in the Hero symbol

```
package com.objects
{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.events.*;
   /**
    * ...
    * @author Anthony Gordon
    */
   [Embed(source='../../../bin/Assets.swf', symbol='Hero')]
   public class Hero extends GameObject
   {   
      private var aKeyPress:Array;
      private var jumpDisabled:Boolean = false;
      //private var heroSprite:MovieClip;

      public function Hero()
      {
         wY = 150;
         wX = 90;
         speed = .5;
         aKeyPress = new Array();
         TheGame.sr.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownListener);
         TheGame.sr.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpListener);
      }

      private function keyDownListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
          //trace("down e.keyCode=" + e.keyCode);         
          aKeyPress[e.keyCode]=true;
      }

      private function keyUpListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
         //trace("up e.keyCode=" + e.keyCode);
         aKeyPress[e.keyCode]=false;
      }

      override public function UpdateObject():void
      {
         Controls();
         updatePosition();
      }

      private function Controls():void
      {

         if (aKeyPress[38])//Key press up
            ;//dy -= speed;         
         else if (aKeyPress[40])//Key press down
            dy += speed;

         if (aKeyPress[37])//left
         {
            dx -= speed;
         }
         else if (aKeyPress[39])//Right
         {
            dx  += speed;
         }

         if (aKeyPress[32]){//space
            jump();
         }


      }//End Controls

      private function jump():void
      {
         if (!jumpDisabled)
         {
            if (onGround)
            {
               dy = -15;
               jumpDisabled = true;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            jumpDisabled = false;            
         }
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the hSprite clip a public variable in the class.

```
public var hSprite:MovieClip;
```